# Convert my full path file name into FileInfo.name in XAML binding

Tags: wpf, binding

This is my model:

```
public class Data
{
    string fileName;
}
```

And inside my `XAML` binding:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="470" Header="File name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" />
```

Now i don't want to see the whole path of my file but only the `File Name`, i know i can add another `class member` and put it but i wonder if i can change this inside my `DisplayMemberBinding`

Comment: You can add converter but adding another property seems easier

Answer (score 0):

I would just add another property which returns the filename, and bind to that instead.